# I got an error in this regular expression str.matches

Tags: regex

```
if(str.matches("[a-zA-Z"]{3}\\s\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}"))
```

in this i got an error that,The method matches(String) in the type String is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)..
 could any body please help me to solve

Comment: which language are you using?.. assuming Java?

Answer (score 2):

> if(str.matches("[a-zA-Z"]{3}\s\d{1,2},\s\d{4}"))

You need to escape `"` in `[a-zA-Z"]` from the string since it is closing the regex string, it should be:

```
if(str.matches("[a-zA-Z\"]{3}\\s\\d{1,2},\\s\\d{4}"))
```

Comment: thank you very much..iam using this code in automation testing tool selenium